# $T_A:\mathbb{T}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^d$ is $|\det A|$ to one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A\in M_d (\mathbb{Z})$ be a $d\times d$ invertible matrix with integer entries, and consider the induced map $T_A:\mathbb{T}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{T}^d$ given by $x\mapsto Ax \pmod 1$, where $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. I need to show that $T_A$ is $|\det A|$ to one, meaning that, for each $y\in \mathbb{T}^d$,
>
> $$\#(\{x:T_Ax=y\})=|\det A|,$$
>
> where $\#$ denotes cardinality.

I'm thinking of using Cramer's rule. Namely, denoting by $A_i(y)$ the matrix obtained by replacing the $i$-th column of $A$ with the $d$-dimensional vector $y$, if we have

$$Ax=y$$

$$Az=y+\xi$$

with $\xi\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ an integer vector, we get that:

$$z_i=\frac{\det (A_i(y+\xi))}{\det A}=\frac{\det (A_i(y))+\det(A_i(\xi)}{\det A}=x_i+\frac{\det (A_i(\xi))}{\det A}$$

which tells us the relationship between $x$ and $z$ if we know that $Ax\equiv Ay \pmod{\mathbb{Z}^n}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

While I'm reasonably convinced Cramer's rule is the way to go, I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $T_A$ is a group homomorphism, so we need only find the order of its kernel.

Consider $A$ acting on $\Bbb R^d$. It's a homomorphism of Abelian groups.
The kernel of $T_A$ corresponds to $A^{-1}[\Bbb Z^d]/\Bbb Z^d$. This is a quotient of Abelian groups. I find it
more convenient to map this by $A$ to $\Bbb Z^d/A[\Bbb Z^d]$. This is
an isomorphic group to $A^{-1}[\Bbb Z^d]/\Bbb Z^d$.

Let $\Lambda=A[\Bbb Z^d]$. As $A$ multiplies areas by $D=|\det A|$ then
$\Lambda$ is a lattice whose fundamental region $F$ has area $D$, that is $D$ times that of $\Bbb Z^d$. Thus $F$ has $D$ elements of $\Bbb Z^d$
and so the quotient group has size $D$.

If you don't like this geometric argument, you can indeed use the theory of the Smith Norma Form to show that $\Bbb Z^d$ has a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_d$ with $Av_i=c_i v_i$ and $D=|c_1\cdots c_d|$.
In this representation it's clear that $\Bbb Z^d/A[\Bbb Z^d]$
has order $|c_1|\cdots|c_d|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a bit rusty on my tilings, so I'm not following the geometric argument; how can you conclude that the fundamental region of $\Lambda$ has $D$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}^d$?

Comment: Just that it has volume $D$. OK maybe not exactly $D$ if some lie on the boundary, but if you translate it so that the boundary avoid $\Bbb Z^d$ then there will be exactly $D$ lattice points within.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow, but it's a tad too geometric for my tastes. Is there a more elementary algebraic proof, without having to appeal to the Smith normal form?